Who is Rudolf Bach?
I've googled but have not found anything about mathematician Rudolf Bach. In Riemannian or semi-Riemannian geometry such as general relativity, Conformal geometry, Wave propagation theory such as Huygens Principle, "Vaccum" Yang-Mills theory, Fefferman Graham ambient metric construction (this list can be extended for sure) in 4 dimensions a symmetric, trace free, divergence-free, and conformally (co)invariant tensor namely the Bach tensor pops up naturally. Could anyone share any source of information about Bach's life, education, etc? Thanks so much.

See 2012 republication of 1921 paper:

Rudolf Bach was a pseudonym. His actual name was Rudolf Förster. R.Bach Deceased on 1941.

See the Editorial note by Hubert Goenner:

Rudolf Förster (1885–1941) studied mathematics in Göttingen and received his PhD
with David Hilbert in 1908. He then worked as an engineer with the manufacturer Krupp in Essen. From Nov. 1917 to March 1918 he corresponded with A. Einstein on an extension of general relativity to include the electromagnetic field via a skew-symmetric metric. By his employer, he was forbidden to publish. Therefore he assumed the pen-name R. Bach [emphasis mine. Footnote: Correspondence and annotations in: The Collected Papers of Albert Einstein, Vol. 8, Part A: 1914–1917, Part B: 1918. R Schulmann, A.J. Kox, M. Janssen, and Jozef Illy, editors. Docs. 398, 400, 420, 439, 463, 467, and 485. Princeton University Press 1998].


How confident are we that this is accurate? I cannot find evidence that anybody by the name of Rudolf Förster was a doctoral candidate under Hilbert. I did, however, find  the PhD thesis of a Rudolf Förster who was born in Chemnitz in 1885, studied mathematics at the universities of Göttingen and Leipzig and received his PhD in 1908 from the latter institution (with Otto Hölder and Karl Rohn acting as examiners of his dissertation).

Peter Havas, "The General-Relativistic Two-Body Problem and the Einstein-Silberstein Controversy." In John Earman, Michel Janssen, John D. Norton (eds.), The Attraction of Gravitation: New Studies in the History of General Relativity,
provides a slightly different and more detailed biographical sketch of R. Förster, based on material from the Einstein Archives that is currently unavailable online. Förster's last employer was Siemens-Schuckert ...

... and I was able to find some corroboration in the form of a notice about a 1928 patent by a Dr. phil. Rudolf Förster in Nuremberg assigned to Siemens-Schuckert.

Zentralblatt lists 7 of his publications, and recognizes his name as Rudolf Förster.
